# How to set the dimensions of a view programatically using sdp in andorid?

Tags: java, android

I want to programmatically set the dimensions of `TextView`. But I'm using `sdp` and `ssp` values. How can I use these values to set the dimensions of a textview programatically.

```
TextView tasks = new TextView(this);
tasks.setText(name);
tasks.setTextSize(??);
tasks.setMargin(??)
ViewGroup.LayoutParams l1 = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height??); // what is the height input here?
```

And how to set the text size (ssp) and margin/padding (sdp)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have 2 option for you.

1. If you just want set text size/ margin for only one screen size. Create file `dimens` on `values` folder. And use that code `getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_name)`. The point is `dimens` just allow  dp, sp and px. But I think that is enough.
2. In case you want set for multi-screen. You can use that lib `com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android` and call multi-dimension like that `getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._1sdp)`

Answer (score 3):

You could make ur dimens.xml file and enter your desired margins/dimensions for each density.

I would suggest using a library from https://github.com/intuit/sdp

You could use this to set your margins or dimensions using

```
Java ->
getResources.getDimension(R.dimen._**sdp);

Kotlin ->
resources.getDimension(R.dimen._**sdp)
```

If u want progmatically set text size or sp sizes, use this https://github.com/intuit/ssp

```
Java ->
tasks.setTextSize(getResources.getDimension(R.dimen._**ssp);

Kotlin ->
tasks.setTextSize(resources.getDimension(R.dimen._**ssp)
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

in Kotlin I solved it this way

```
headerTimer.layoutParams.height = resources.getDimension(com.intuit.sdp.R.dimen._180sdp).toInt()
```

and it works correctly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).